# How do I remove the Maximized MDI Child's name from the MDI Parent's Title Bar?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, mdi, mdichild, mdiparent

I am making an MDI application in `Visual Basic` with `Windows Forms`. When an MDI Child is maximized in `Windows Forms`, the child's title name is displayed in the title bar of the MDI Parent. I don't like the way this is formatted and I would like to disable the text from showing in my MDI Parent's title. Here is what it looks like:

[image: A windows form with an MDI Child maximized showing the child's title name in the parent's title bar.]

I have tried changing the form's `Text` property whenever it was changed and if it had a ']' at the end *(like when an MDI Child is maximized)*

```
    Private Sub WorkHost_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.TextChanged
        If Me.Text.EndsWith("]") Then
            Me.Text = "Atlas Departure Control"
        End If
    End Sub
```

This did not have any effect as the MDI Child's name isn't actually shown in the form's `Text` property.

I also tried having a single button to change the text *(in case of any timing issues when the form was maximized)*

```
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Me.Text = "Atlas Departure Control"
    End Sub
```

I am completely lost here and would appreciate any help I recieve.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the `Text` of Child Form as `string.Empty`. This would remove the Child's title being shown in Main Title when maximized.

```
childForm.Text = String.Empty
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked well. I used the Form.Resize event to detect when the form was maximized and taken out of maximized so I can remove the text when necessary :D